# Why does <T extends Enum<T> & SomeInterface> compile, but not <T extends SomeInterface & Enum<T>>?

Tags: java, generics, enums, type-bounds

I can't understand why the method2 does not compile whereas method1 does compile.
I am using Eclipse with JavaSE 1.7 and I got the following error on method2:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The type Enum<T> is not an interface; it cannot be specified as a bounded parameter
> - Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Enum<E>> of    the type Enum<E>

```
public class Test {

    public interface SomeInterface {

    }

    public static <T extends Enum<T> & SomeInterface> T method1() {
        return null;
    }

    public static <T extends SomeInterface & Enum<T>> T method2() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at the syntax for type parameter bounds in [JLS 8.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) you'll see:

```
TypeBound:
    extends TypeVariable 
    extends ClassOrInterfaceType {AdditionalBound}

AdditionalBound:
    & InterfaceType
```

In other words, only the *first* type specified can be a class - all the rest have to be interfaces.

Aside from anything else, this prevents multiple classes being specified.

It also mirrors the way that when declaring a class, you have to put the class it's extending first, then the interfaces it implements - not the other way round.

Comment: Beaten by seconds. *Skeet!* \*shakes fist\*

Answer (score 6):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html):

> A type variable with multiple bounds is a subtype of all the types listed in the bound. If one of the bounds is a class, it must be specified first. For example:

```
Class A { /* ... */ }
interface B { /* ... */ }
interface C { /* ... */ }

class D <T extends A & B & C> { /* ... */ }
```

> If bound A is not specified first, you get a compile-time error:

```
class D <T extends B & A & C> { /* ... */ }  // compile-time error
```

Since in your example `method2` has the interface `SomeInterface` first, it shows the compiler-error